# React native maps : onPress marker event is delay

Tags: android, react-native, events, marker, react-native-maps

In my case, I have 30 markers and I set `tracksViewChanges` to `false` and the maps work very well. But the event is delayed so much. All event on the screen which includes the mapview. When I press the marker, it is delay 5-7 seconds or later. (Android)
Everything is working well on iOS.